How to use a V1ProjectedVolumeSource in an Airflow DAG?
I'm trying to get the following to work in an Airflow DAG, but the pod won't init. As far, as I can tell the corresponding configuration works in a pod that I've been testing separately in Openshift.
Would be grateful if anyone can identify any next steps for troubleshooting.
config = k8s.V1Volume(
    name="config",
    config_map=k8s.V1ProjectedVolumeSource(
        sources=[
            k8s.V1ConfigMapVolumeSource(name="config1"),
            k8s.V1ConfigMapVolumeSource(name="config2"),
            ]
    ),
)

config_mt = k8s.V1VolumeMount(name="config", mount_path="/conf")

The equivalent yaml that was working.
volumeMounts:
  - name: config
   mountPath: /conf
   readOnly: True
volumes:
  - name: config
      projected:
        sources:
        - configMap:
            name: config1
        - configMap:
            name: config2

